# Left join ou Sub-Select? qual possui a melhor perfomance?

Tags: sql, desempenho

Estou estudando qual das querys abaixo, teria melhor performance.
Então, escrevi as duas e executei no mesmo banco com os mesmo dados:

Query 1:

```
                                select a.numeroOp as OP, a.codigo as CÓDIGO, (a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) as QNT, 
                        (CONVERT(varchar(100), a.numeroProjeto) + '_' + CONVERT(varchar(100), a.itemProjeto)) as keyColumnOp, 
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.montagem) as decimal(18,2)) as MONT, 
                            case when d.maq = 'MONT' then 1 else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.bancada) as decimal(18,2)) as BANC, 
                            case when e.maq = 'BANC' then 1 else 0 end as BANCsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trP1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TP 1',
                            case when f.maq = 'TP 1' then 1 else 0 end as TP1semana, 
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trP2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TP 2',
                            case when g.maq = 'TP 2' then 1 else 0 end as TP2semana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trQ1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TQ 1', 
                            case when h.maq = 'TQ 1' then 1 else 0 end as TQ1semana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trQ2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TQ 2', 
                            case when i.maq = 'TQ 2' then 1 else 0 end as TQ2semana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trCarvao) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TCAR',
                            case when j.maq = 'TCAR' then 1 else 0 end as TCARsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.corte) as decimal(18,2)) as 'CORTE', 
                            case when k.maq = 'CORTE' then 1 else 0 end as CORTEsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.fr1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'F 1',
                            case when l.maq = 'F 1' then 1 else 0 end as F1semana, 
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.fr2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'F 2',
                            case when m.maq = 'F 2' then 1 else 0 end as F2semana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.retifica) as decimal(18,2)) as 'RET',
                            case when n.maq = 'RET' then 1 else 0 end as RETsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trcnc1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TC 1', 
                            case when d.maq = 'TC 1' then 1 else 0 end as TC1semana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trCnc2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TC 2',
                            case when d.maq = 'TC 2' then 1 else 0 end as TC2semana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.cnc) as decimal(18,2)) as 'CNC', 
                            case when d.maq = 'CNC' then 1 else 0 end as CNCsemana, case 
                                                                                                        when a.processoTempoPlan Is null then 0
                                                                                                        else a.processoTempoPlan
                                                                                                        end as PROD, a.idNo

                        from Pcp_Op as a
                        left join vendas_itensEntregar as b
                        on a.numeroProjeto = b.projeto and a.itemProjeto = b.item
                        left join pcp_tempoProcessos as c
                        on a.codigo = c.codigo
                        left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as d
                        on a.numeroProjeto = d.projeto and a.itemProjeto = d.item and a.idNo = d.idNo and d.maq = 'MONT'
                        left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as e
                        on a.numeroProjeto = e.projeto and a.itemProjeto = e.item and a.idNo = e.idNo and e.maq = 'BANC'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as f
                        on a.numeroProjeto = f.projeto and a.itemProjeto = f.item and a.idNo = f.idNo and f.maq = 'TP 1'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as g
                        on a.numeroProjeto = g.projeto and a.itemProjeto = g.item and a.idNo = g.idNo and g.maq = 'TP 2'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as h
                        on a.numeroProjeto = h.projeto and a.itemProjeto = h.item and a.idNo = h.idNo and h.maq = 'TQ 1'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as i
                        on a.numeroProjeto = i.projeto and a.itemProjeto = i.item and a.idNo = i.idNo and i.maq = 'TQ 2'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as j
                        on a.numeroProjeto = j.projeto and a.itemProjeto = j.item and a.idNo = j.idNo and j.maq = 'TCAR'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as k
                        on a.numeroProjeto = k.projeto and a.itemProjeto = k.item and a.idNo = k.idNo and k.maq = 'CORTE'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as l
                        on a.numeroProjeto = l.projeto and a.itemProjeto = l.item and a.idNo = l.idNo and l.maq = 'F 1'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as m
                        on a.numeroProjeto = m.projeto and a.itemProjeto = m.item and a.idNo = m.idNo and m.maq = 'F 2'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as n
                        on a.numeroProjeto = n.projeto and a.itemProjeto = n.item and a.idNo = n.idNo and n.maq = 'RET'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as o
                        on a.numeroProjeto = o.projeto and a.itemProjeto = o.item and a.idNo = o.idNo and o.maq = 'TC 1'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as p
                        on a.numeroProjeto = p.projeto and a.itemProjeto = p.item and a.idNo = p.idNo and p.maq = 'TC 2'
                                left join Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as q
                        on a.numeroProjeto = q.projeto and a.itemProjeto = q.item and a.idNo = q.idNo and q.maq = 'CNC'
                        where b.statusSql <> 'Ok'
```

Query 2:

```
insirselect a.numeroOp as OP, a.codigo as CÓDIGO, (a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) as QNT, 
                        (CONVERT(varchar(100), a.numeroProjeto) + '_' + CONVERT(varchar(100), a.itemProjeto)) as keyColumnOp, 
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.montagem) as decimal(18,2)) as MONT, 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'MONT') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.bancada) as decimal(18,2)) as BANC, 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'BANC') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trP1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TP 1',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TP 1') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trP2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TP 2',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TP 2') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trQ1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TQ 1', 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TQ 1') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trQ2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TQ 2', 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TQ 2') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trCarvao) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TCAR',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TCAR') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.corte) as decimal(18,2)) as 'CORTE', 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'CORTE') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.fr1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'F 1',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'F 1') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.fr2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'F 2',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'F 2') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.retifica) as decimal(18,2)) as 'RET',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'RET') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trcnc1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TC 1', 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TC 1') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trCnc2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TC 2',
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'TC 2') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana,
                        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.cnc) as decimal(18,2)) as 'CNC', 
                            case 
                            when (select count(id) from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos as t where t.projeto = a.numeroProjeto and t.item = a.itemProjeto and t.idno = a.idno and t.maq = 'CNC') > 0 then 1
                            else 0 end as MONTsemana, case
                                                                                                        when a.processoTempoPlan Is null then 0
                                                                                                        else a.processoTempoPlan
                                                                                                        end as PROD, a.idNo

                        from Pcp_Op as a
                        left join vendas_itensEntregar as b
                        on a.numeroProjeto = b.projeto and a.itemProjeto = b.item
                        left join pcp_tempoProcessos as c
                        on a.codigo = c.codigo                      
                        where b.statusSql <> 'Ok'
```

Na query 1, eu utilizo `Left Join` na query 2 eu utilizo  `sub-select`

Então rodei as mesmas, e acompanhei no SQL Profiler:

Resultado Query 1:
[image: SQL PROFILER - QUERY 1]

Resultado Query 2:
[image: SQL PROFILER - QUERY 2]

Pelo que pude analisar, a query 2 levou menos tempo para ser executada, porem realizou maior numero de leitura (Reads) e utilizou menos da capacidade do processador, correto?

Com isso podemos dizer que a Query 2, seria mais eficiente doque a Query 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por Isaac Junior: O mistério de como o SqlServer opera internamente é difícil de resolver.

É bem possível que, em alguns casos, a diferença esteja apenas na sintaxe e o Sql Server opere da mesma forma.

Mas a subquery, teoricamente, teria que que ser executada a cada registro da consulta principal enquanto a tabela do join seria tratada de outra maneira. O que me leva a pensar que o join seja mais performático. Mas, segundo o link abaixo, não há diferença de performance quando as consultas são equivalentes.(Como no caso do seu exemplo)

Veja em: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx Quando as consultas são equivalentes não ha diferença na performance. Mas quando a condição de existência (EXISTS) tem que ser checada a cada registro da query principal, o join tem melhor performance.

Em uma query grande e complexa, subquery pode deixar a consulta mais difícil de ler. Mas é indispensável em outros casos.

Só uso subquery quando a coisa não pode ser feita com Join.

Answer (score 0):

Já experimentou uma solução deste género:

```
select  a.numeroOp as OP, a.codigo as CÓDIGO, (a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) as QNT, 
        (CONVERT(varchar(100), a.numeroProjeto) + '_' + CONVERT(varchar(100), a.itemProjeto)) as keyColumnOp, 
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.montagem) as decimal(18,2)) as MONT, 
            MONTsemana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.bancada) as decimal(18,2)) as BANC, 
            BANCsemana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trP1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TP 1',
            TP1semana, 
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trP2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TP 2',
            TP2semana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trQ1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TQ 1', 
            TQ1semana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trQ2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TQ 2', 
            TQ2semana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trCarvao) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TCAR',
            TCARsemana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.corte) as decimal(18,2)) as 'CORTE', 
            CORTEsemana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.fr1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'F 1',
            F1semana, 
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.fr2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'F 2',
            F2semana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.retifica) as decimal(18,2)) as 'RET',
            RETsemana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trcnc1) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TC 1', 
            TC1semana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.trCnc2) as decimal(18,2)) as 'TC 2',
            TC2semana,
        cast(((a.qntAhProduzir + a.qntParaEstoque) * c.cnc) as decimal(18,2)) as 'CNC', 
            CNCsemana, case 
                        when a.processoTempoPlan Is null then 0
                        else a.processoTempoPlan
                        end as PROD, a.idNo

from Pcp_Op as a
    left join vendas_itensEntregar as b
        on a.numeroProjeto = b.projeto and a.itemProjeto = b.item
    left join pcp_tempoProcessos as c
        on a.codigo = c.codigo

    left join (select   projeto, item, idNo,
                        MONTsemana = max(case when maq = 'MONT' then 1 else 0 end),
                        BANCsemana = max(case when maq = 'BANC' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TP1semana = max(case when maq = 'TP 1' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TP2semana = max(case when maq = 'TP 2' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TQ1semana = max(case when maq = 'TQ 1' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TQ2semana = max(case when maq = 'TQ 2' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TCARsemana = max(case when maq = 'TCAR' then 1 else 0 end),
                        CORTEsemana = max(case when maq = 'CORTE' then 1 else 0 end),
                        F1semana = max(case when maq = 'F 1' then 1 else 0 end),
                        F2semana = max(case when maq = 'F 2' then 1 else 0 end),
                        RETsemana = max(case when maq = 'RET' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TC1semana = max(case when maq = 'TC 1' then 1 else 0 end),
                        TC2semana = max(case when maq = 'TC 2' then 1 else 0 end),
                        CNCsemana = max(case when maq = 'CNC' then 1 else 0 end)
                from Pcp_DistribuiSemanaProcessos
                group by projeto, item, idNo)  d on
        a.numeroProjeto = d.projeto and a.itemProjeto = d.item and a.idNo = d.idNo

where b.statusSql <> 'Ok'
```